# Putting tables in end of paper, then summoning them in text with a command?

Tags: tables

In papers I put the tables at the very end and do something like;

```
\begin{center} Insert Table~\ref{tbl:tab1_1} about here. \end{center}
```

in the body of the paper for a draft. When it comes to finalizing I'll copy and paste the tables into the body of the paper.

This is tedious. Is there a command thingy that I can place in the body of the TeXt to make the table "disappear" from the end of the paper and appear where I've placed the command?

Comment: Why exactly do you place the tables in the end to begin with? How exactly is the disappear/appear thing supposed to happen and when is it supposed to happen?

Comment: I believe that this is standard for working papers in the field of econometrics (this is what I see in 90% of working papers that I've viewed). Put the tables in the end until the paper is finalized. This is also how my co-author is working now so I have to work with that.

I want to have all the tables in the end, then use a command in the body that references a particular table (say "Table 1"), then I want this command to make this "Table 1" disappear from the back of the paper, then appear where I've issued the command, so when I make the PDF it's as if the table was typed into the body.

Comment: I suggest you to write the table data on a separate file, one for each table and then you just use `\input` command to put the table. So, it will be easy to cut and paste those commands.

Also, try to use the `table` environment with the `\caption` command. It is better.

Comment: @Sigur (1) Your first sentence: Yes, good idea. Although my thesis is 26 tables so I might wait to see if another answer comes along. (2) Your second sentence: "It is better" - better than what exactly?

Comment: @IssacM, sorry. I thought that you were using `center` for the tables. But you were using only to inform the place. Well, I believe that you are using the `table` environments, so you can make use of `\listoftables`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `.tex` file with the tables in the bottom and you need to get then moved, then I don't think there is a better way than then copy-paste method.

If the motivation for putting the tables in the bottom whilst editing is to make the `.pdf` file easier to navigate by not having huge tables in the middle of it all, then a solution could be to place

```
\newif\ifshowtables
```

in your preamble and then write your tables as

```
\ifshowtables
\begin{table}
...
\end{table}
\else
Here the awesome table will appear!
\fi
```

Then the table will be included if you include `\showtablestrue` in your preamble and the text will be included instead if you include `\showtablesfalse` in your preamble. You can also just remove the text and the `\else`, then it is only a matter of whether the table appears or not.

In my opinion this is not that complicated to remember, so if you are working with co-authors, then you might be able to convince them to use the same method.

This of course also works with other things than tables.

Comment: Consider combining this solution with a previous comment by replacing the `\begin{table} ... \end{table}` block with `\input{tableN}` and then, at the end of your document, an if block that inputs all the tables when `showtables` is false. Then you have both versions with no cut and paste.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [endfloat](http://mirrors.cicku.me/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/endfloat/endfloat.pdf) package. It is consistent with the finance/econ papers I read and only requires and on/off, plus a few other tweaks if you have special needs.